Incorrect screen time on Digital Wellbeing
I check my screen time through the 'Digital Wellbeing and parental controls' option in the Settings of my MI phone. (Redmi Note 7)
I manually calculated today's usage and it's around 2- 2½ hours. However, settings show 10 hr 30 min. I toggled to see the 'hourly' distribution and saw many of the apps being used at 4/5 AM. My phone was switched off during this time and I was asleep. It says I used 4 hr of YouTube today, yet the stats on the YouTube app itself says 30 mins.
Is this a common bug? Or should I be concerned?

Could be a bug or you have malware running that "watches" videos and their ads in background for ad fraud. As your phone was release in 2019 I assume the security update support has run out years ago, right?

@Robert Probably, but how do you check that? It's also a little weird - my phone claims I used Google Docs for an hour at 3 AM today. Not sure how the ad/malware logic would work here.

Possibly related: Digital Wellbeing - How does it measure the usage of the applications? (not yet answered)

Assuming that switched off actually means locked, then as mentioned by others, you could have malware running.
Even though your phone is old and may lack newer security updates, you can run an anti-virus or anti-malwate app. I use Kaspersky on my mobiles. The free one does most things, the only drawback is you have to update it manually. I am not associated with Kaspersky.
I recommend you install one such app on your phone

Although I can't completely confirm, I think my phone was switched off during that time (not locked). I could be wrong, though. I did use an anti-virus app and it didn't detect anything so I'm assuming this was just a bug.
